# SVG is invisible but exists in DOM

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a bunch of line elements created with D3 but the strange thing is that they're appearing in the DOM and when I mouseover them I see it being highlighted but there isn't anything there, everything is just blank. The code somewhat looks like this and the CSS has some weird webkit-transform-origin stuff. Does anyone know what is wrong? (screenshot of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoPy.jpg)

```
<div>
<svg width="1000" height="700">
<line x1="420" y1="470" x2="394.9078930250818" y2="369.0723716341295" id="id-1" style="stroke-    width: 10px; color: red;"></line>
</svg>
</div>

-webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
-webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
-webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;
```

Comment: Do you really have `stroke- [blank spaces]   width` in your code, or do you have `stroke-width`?

Comment: @mg1075: You can see from the screencap that the original code is correct (`stroke-width`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`color` doesn't do anything. Set [`stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke) instead. At the moment, all of your lines are getting rendered with no stroke at all, which makes them invisible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change color to stroke. For instance:

```
<line x1="420" y1="470" x2="394.9078930250818" y2="369.0723716341295" id="id-1" style="stroke-width: 10px; stroke: red;"></line>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Tried to set stroke-width - did not help. Fixed it with correct x position of the element.